# Can't fetch or parse external bank account info from Stripe when retrieving external bank account

Tags: c#, json, stripe-payments

I can't figure out how to get the info I need from the IExternalAccount object

When I create a connected account or just fetch a external account attached to the connected account I want to extract info from that external account (last4, bank name, etc)

It looks like it might be some type of JSON object, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the data.

Here is what it looks like when I [create a new connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=dotnet) that has an attached external bank account. It returns a Stripe.Account back to the server.

```
Stripe.Account account = await service.CreateAsync(options);
// want to fetch some of the data for the attached external bank account
account.ExternalAccounts.Data[0]
```

The external bank account I want to retrieve properties from looks like this:

```js
{<Stripe.BankAccount@18273431 id=ba_1JHFX8QmnFNIHnUVwRfBMvc3> JSON: {
  "id": "ba_1JHFX9QmnFNIHnUVwGfBM2we",
  "object": "bank_account",
  "account": "acct_1JHFX9QmnFNIHbTy",
  "account_holder_name": "Sam Smith",
  "account_holder_type": "individual",
  "available_payout_methods": [
    "standard"
  ],
  "bank_name": "STRIPE TEST BANK",
  "country": "US",
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "default_for_currency": true,
  "fingerprint": "YjcUH1SBdksgZfC5",
  "last4": "6789",
  "metadata": {},
  "routing_number": "110000000",
  "status": "new"
}}
```

**PROBLEM** - I can fetch the id and object like this but I can't get the others (ex. last4, satus, etc). I get an exception if I try to use them in a property.

> account.ExternalAccounts.Data[0].Id => "ba_1JHFX9QmnFNIHnUVwGfBM2we"
> account.ExternalAccounts.Data[0].Object => "bank_account"
> account.ExternalAccounts.Data[0].account_holder_name // error
> account.ExternalAccounts.Data[0].Account_holder_name // error
> account.ExternalAccounts.Data[0].AccountHolderName // error

> error CS1061: 'IExternalAccount' does not contain a definition for 'account_holder_name' and no accessible extension method 'account_holder_name' accepting a first argument of type 'IExternalAccount' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The [Stripe page](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/retrieve?lang=dotnet) shows a JSON object being returned, but I'm not really getting that from the .Net code.

Can someone please help?

**Edit** - I have found 1 way to extract the external account values, but it seems laborious and not the best way. I'd like to see if anyone knows a better way.

```
Stripe.Account account = await service.CreateAsync(options);
JObject data = JObject.Parse(account.StripeResponse.Content);
fullName = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["account_holder_name"];
bankName = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["bank_name"];
country = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["country"];
currency = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["currency"];
fingerprint = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["fingerprint"];
last4 = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["last4"];
routingNumber = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["routing_number"]; 
status = (string)data["external_accounts"]["data"][0]["status"];
```

Comment: What you can do is really just use the `Account. ExternalAccounts ` property. This property is a list of `IExternalAccount` interface which you can simply cast it to `BankAccount` e.g. `var bc = Account.ExternalAccounts[0] as BankAccount`

Comment: Only fix I would make is that ExternalAccounts cannot be indexed, only enumerated so you have to use something like ExternalAccounts.First() as BankAccount. But thanks for the help.